# Should we expect the compiler to optimize away variables that are only used once in the function body?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, compiler-optimization, move-semantics

I've seen it recommended (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/), for example) that if you want to create a copy of a parameter to a function, then you should pass it by value so that the copy is done automatically in the initialization list.

I.e., instead of writing

```cpp
void some_function_ref(Some_class const& input)
{
  Some_class copy_of_input(input);
  // Do something with copy_of_input
}
```

, we should write

```cpp
void some_function_val(Some_class input)
{
  // Do something with input
}
```

.  In C++11, there's an elegant reason for this: the second case will choose between calling the copy constructor or the move constructor depending on whether it is passed an lvalue or an rvalue, whereas the first case always calls the copy constructor.

For example, if we call

```cpp
some_function_ref(function_that_returns_some_class())
```

, then the program will create a temporary to store the return value of `function_that_returns_some_class`, and then make a copy of this temporary inside the function.  Whereas if we call

```cpp
some_function_val(function_that_returns_some_class())
```

, then the program will create a temporary as before, but will now *move* the temporary into the function and use that value internally. We have avoided the needless copy.

However, `some_function_ref` has advantages of its own: if we want to make our code easy to debug, then it might be helpful to see the value of `input` that was passed into the function. If `some_function` has been passed an lvalue, then we can see this value by inspecting the value of the variable in the enclosing scope. However, if it has been passed an rvalue, we might have no way of seeing what it is.

Of course, there is a reason for this: if the function has been called with an rvalue, then `some_function_val` will use the move constructor on the temporary, which means that it the old value no longer exists! From an optimization point of view, this is great, since we've avoided an extra copy. From a debugging point of view, it's not so good.

What would be really nice is if we could see the original value of `input` in an unoptimized debug build of the code, but have the value moved in an optimized release build. For that reason, I would be tempted to use the first version (`some_function_ref`), under the assumption that the compiler will optimize away the copy and call the move constructor instead if I've turned optimization on, effectively converting `some_function_ref` into `some_function_val`.

Is this a reasonable assumption to make? Is the compiler (think gcc, clang etc.) smart enough to realize that `input` is only used to make a copy and optimize `some_function_ref` to do the same thing as `some_function_val`?

Comment: "*we should write*" - no, it is actually a bad practice because `input` constructor and destructor will be invoked on the caller side. That is if you have 100 places with invocation of `some_function_val` accepting parameter by value it will cause object construction, destruction (and possibly extra exception handling) code to be inserted 100 times instead of just one aka code bloat. Things get even worse if class construction involves a dll boundary call.

Comment: @VTT That's a valid point, and one that is addressed in the article I linked to. If `some_function_val` is being called 100 times, then you can write a wrapper function (taking a reference) around `some_function_val` and have external code call that wrapper. In fact, that could be a good solution to the problems with debugging as well.

Comment: @VTT godbold disagrees with you, in both cases the code is identical: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ME-Lgg

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Your example is not correct because you create temporary objects in both cases. [correct example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/y8YP5U)

Comment: @VTT Here is an example corresponding to the question: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3S4ijX Identical code again.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Well, output will be obviously identical if you create temporary objects in both cases. But accepting a reference will help to avoid creation of temporary when we pass some existing object.

Comment: @VTT I think I misunderstood the article. The idea is that there's a trade-off between the problem you mentioned and the possible benefits of the copy elision, so you have to be careful. However, if you've written your function to pass its parameters by value, and this is causing problems, then it's easy to transform it into a by-reference function using a wrapper.